# Make a Pivot in bottom of Page UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

In the page of Microsoft, I see the type of menu like the image. Please I want to know how to do pivot menu like this.

I want to make a pivot menu like this image in bottom of page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1672) open for this in the UWP Community Toolkit to provide a style for this type of tab.

I have a [branch](https://github.com/michael-hawker/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/mhawker/pivot-styles) here with some initial work.  Here's my current work on that [style](https://github.com/michael-hawker/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/mhawker/pivot-styles/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/Pivot/Styles/SystemTabStyle.xaml).

To get them on the bottom though, you'll need to modify the [default pivot style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx) and move the `ItemsPresenter` above the `PivotHeaderPanel` in the **PivotLayoutElement** Grid.